# How To insert a xml webservices response to a table? - Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, web-services

i got a xml web response that i would like to insert into a table in oracle. I call to a soap web services from a StoredProcedure in Oracle and the i want to insert to a table. This is the Xml Response that i want to insert to a table in Oracle. can you help me?

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <ProcesarLiquidacionResponse xmlns="http://wsAffinityHPExtream.Servicio/wsAffinityHPExtream" 
            xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <respuesta xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LP.Affinity.BusinessEntities">
                    <a:listaRespuestas>
                        <a:DetalleRespuestaBE>
                            <a:Codigo>R001</a:Codigo>
                            <a:Descripcion>La planilla liquidó satisfactoriamente.</a:Descripcion>
                        </a:DetalleRespuestaBE>
                    </a:listaRespuestas>
                </respuesta>
        </ProcesarLiquidacionResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: XML is just text.  Store it either as an XMLTYPE column or CLOB.  You got a web response how?  What language are you using?  Read the documentation - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb02rep.htm#ADXDB0200

Comment: I call the web service with a SP in Oracle, is a web service made in .net C#.